# Difference between dynamic rectangles and circles in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am confused about why I am able to create an svg and even have circles defined in the DOM of the page, however, the circles are not showing up on the page as they would with rectangles.

```
    var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 200)
                        .attr("height", 200);

    var populations = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(jsonCircle)
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle");

    var populationAttributes = populations
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                    .attr("radius", function (d) {return d.radius;})
                    .style("fill", function (d) {return d.color;});
```

I am trying to follow the example in dashing d3 exactly except with a circle instead of a rectangle (https://www.dashingd3js.com/dynamic-svg-coordinate-space)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attributes for a [circle](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/shapes.html#CircleElement) are not x, y and radius they are cx, cy and r.